# Using bash shell from within PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell

In my terminal window (using Max OS X) my shell is bash. However when I run a command in PHP via shell_exec or backtick operators I see that PHP is using the Bourne Shell (sh). Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

From within my terminal window:

```
$ echo $0
- bash
```

Also if I call php as follows:

```
$ php -r "echo shell_exec('echo $0');"
-bash
```

However, if I create a script called test.php with the following:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('echo $0'); ?>
```

And then run test php I get the following:

```
$ php test.php
sh
```

I'm wanting to use the bash shell when calling shell_exec - why is it choosing the Bourne shell and can I force it to use bash?

Thanks!

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the quotes in your second command:

```
$ php -r 'echo shell_exec("echo $0");'
sh
```

With the quotes as you had them in your question, the variable `$0` is expanded before the command is sent to `php`.

If you want to force the use of Bash, you could do something like:

```
php -r '$cmd="echo \\\$0"; echo shell_exec("/bin/bash -c \"$cmd\"");'
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>It probably reads the SHELL environment variable.</s> Disregard that, putenv() didn't work.

Try to just run the command you want with bash, like

```
shell_exec("bash script.sh");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. your PHP script is executed by the web server (say, Apache)
2. the web server is executed with the rights of a special user account,

one of the possible (but not optimal) solutions would be to change the default shell of the user account under which your web server is executed.