# Reading user command line input with PHP with readline, but bash is not default shell

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line-interface, readline

I wrote a PHP script and I'm trying to read user input from the command line. I started of with

```
$myVar = exec('read myVar; echo $myVar;');
```

which worked fine, but when typing the input the arrow keys didn't work the way it should. I learned that this could be solved with the -e switch, so it became:

```
$myVar = exec('read -e myVar; echo $myVar;');
```

Now this worked like a charm in my development envionment but unfortunately it seems like in our production environment PHP doesn't use a bash shell and doesn't support the -e switch, and it's probably not easy to change this.

According to [the third answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701993/using-bash-shell-from-within-php)  one can force PHP to use bash, so it became:

```
$myVar = exec('/bin/bash -c "read -e myVar; echo $myVar"');
```

Now, unfortunately this doesn't work as the variable `myVar` is not set.

When I run the commands directly from the command line `$myVar` (the shell variable) is set with whatever my input is, and consequently echo'ed

However when using the -c option, either in a PHP-exec() or directly on the command line like this:

```
/bin/bash -c "read -e myVar; echo $myVar";
```

`$myVar` isn't set at all, and an empty string (or whatever was the previous value of `$myVar`) is echo'ed

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Have you considered using [readline()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php)?

Comment: Yes, I did. And quit trying after I found out that it wasn't supported on my development environment, however indeed it works fine on production, so I think I'll just have to make that work on development, or could even go with a 'function_exists()' switch for the time being. So thanks, kind of forgot about that.

Still makes me wonder though how the above doesn't work.

Comment: Are you developing against a different version of PHP than what you have on production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `$myVar` is being interpreted before being passed to bash. The following will work by escaping the `$` before it's passed to the shell:

`/bin/bash -c "read -e myVar; echo \$myVar"`

Also you can shorten it a little by making use of `$REPLY`

`/bin/bash -c "read -e; echo \$REPLY"`

Comment: That's just it! Thanks :-)

Comment: No problem @btum81 :-)

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is correct.
The solution is to use the correct escape sequence:

```
$myVar = exec ('/bin/bash -c \'read -e myVar; echo $myVar \'');
```